# expect script to automate utility

Tags: linux, scripting, input, expect

we want to automate the utility - "Setup ambari-server"
this utility ask 4 default questions , and all answers should be default (no)

how to use expect script to automate this utility ?

```
ambari-server setup
Using python  /usr/bin/python
Setup ambari-server
Checking SELinux...
SELinux status is 'disabled'
Ambari-server daemon is configured to run under user 'ambari'. Change this setting [y/n] (n)?
Adjusting ambari-server permissions and ownership...
Checking firewall status...
Checking JDK...
Do you want to change Oracle JDK [y/n] (n)?
Checking GPL software agreement...
GPL License for LZO: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.en.html
Enable Ambari Server to download and install GPL Licensed LZO packages [y/n] (n)?
Completing setup...
Configuring database...
Enter advanced database configuration [y/n] (n)?
Configuring database...
Default properties detected. Using built-in database.
Configuring ambari database...
Checking PostgreSQL...
Configuring local database...
Configuring PostgreSQL...
Backup for pg_hba found, reconfiguration not required
Creating schema and user...
done.
Creating tables...
done.
Extracting system views...
............
Adjusting ambari-server permissions and ownership...
Ambari Server 'setup' completed successfully.
```

Comment: It may be enough to pipe 4 newlines: `echo -e "\n\n\n\n" | ambari-server setup`. (Do not confuse newline `\n` with key `n`).

Comment: `printf "\n\n\n\n"` would be more portable.

Comment: have you tried using `autoexpect` to generate something to start with?